# How to remove multiple lines and make it a single line in particular cell

Tags: excel

There are more than 1000's of rows in my excel and I want to format the lines such that I need to remove multiple lines and make it a single line in particular cell. Please help

PS: When I click on Merge and Center option, I can achieve for one row, But if I use it for entire sheet, doesn't work out.

Currently it appears as below:

[image: current]

Expected :

[image: expected]

Comment: What have you tried and what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Sorry I tried multiple things but did not reach to the desired result as I am new to excel. So thoughtof asking some expert advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work, assuming the unique key is the combination of **Adapter** and **Date**, if not then it can be adjusted.

```
=LET(AB,A2:B6, A,TAKE(AB,,1), B,DROP(AB,,1), C,C2:C6, ux,UNIQUE(AB),
 uxA,TAKE(ux,,1), uxB,DROP(ux,,1), out, MAP(uxA,uxB, 
 LAMBDA(x,y,TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,FILTER(C,(A=x)*(B=y))))),HSTACK(ux,out))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

The new line inside the cell is there, but I don't know why my Excel doesn't get visualized. It should be, as per this [link](https://exceljet.net/formulas/add-a-line-break-with-a-formula). It is there because if I do `TEXTSPLIT(G2, CHAR(10))` it gets split.